# Title does not update in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to update my stack navigator title using setParams in navigation 4.0. 
It doesn't seem to update anything. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

I need to update the title of a route in a specific screen. 
So I wrote myself the following in a class component to update the title.

I'm grabbing the options in the following manner:

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: navigation.getParam('Title'),
    };
  };
```

then trying to set them

```
  updateTitle = () => {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ Title: 'Updated!' })
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    {this.updateTitle}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

defined the navigationOptions method

When this method runs, you are very likely not to have access to the properties that are needed to set the navigator state, so simply return the current parameters, this is:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
    return params;
};
```

implemented the title construction in componentDidMount, setting the state:

```
componentDidMount(){
    t = "title";
    this.props.navigation.setParams({title: t });
}
```